# How to get highlight style used for the text under cursor?

Tags: colorscheme, highlight

There is some text under my cursor that specific highlight is used. I do not know which highlight is that. I can type `:highlight` and randomly guess which could that be. Is there a method to just place my cursor over some text and then do `:get_highlight_under_cursor`-ish command to get the highlight used to display the character under the cursor?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I’ve closed your question as a duplicate; please [edit] to let us know if it doesn’t answer your question and how.

Comment: No worries, gj, thanks, couldn't find it! Didn't find to search under "identify syntax region" ;)